# sort by date in users

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, users, order, columns

add a column with date, I bring the date with a shortcode from a plugin, I have the problem when trying to order it.

how could i do

function fc_new_modify_user_table( $column ) {

```
$column['vencimiento'] = 'Vencimiento';
return $column;
```

}

add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'fc_new_modify_user_table' );

function fc_new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {

```
switch ($column_name) {

    case 'vencimiento' :
        $fechavenc = do_shortcode('[wcra_show_expiring_dates user_id="' . $user_id . '"]');
    return   $fechavenc;  
    default:
}
return $val;
```

}

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'fc_new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );

function wpse_user_table_list_sortable_columns($columns) {

```
$columns['vencimiento'] = 'Vencimiento';

return $columns;
```

}

add_filter('manage_users_sortable_columns', 'wpse_user_table_list_sortable_columns');

function change_user_order( $args ){

```
if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) ) {

    $args['vencimiento'] = $args['orderby'];

}

return $args;
```

}

add_filter( 'users_list_table_query_args', 'change_user_order' );